# Put status Bar Color in LightContent

Tags: ios, swift3, statusbar, uistatusbar

I try to put my Status Bar in Light Content.
The problem is that I have set `View controller-based status bar 
appearance` to YES .

[image]

In my ViewController I put :

```
override open var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

I also try to put this in my AppDelegate :

```
application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

After thats I still have a Dark (black) Status Bar.

Comment: Have you checked whether preferredStatusBarStyle is getting called by putting break point ?

Comment: did you Check with NO ?

Comment: Please check with NO

Comment: I can't Check with NO

Comment: @AravindAR preferredStatusBarStyle is never call

Answer (score 2):

**ios 10 and swift 3**

Change in info.plist the row View controller-based status bar appearance and set it to NO

Change in appDelegate.swift in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

In perticular viewcontroller use

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
   return .lightContent
}
```

Comment: I can't set it to NO because when I load a Youtube Video with the WebView the status bar disappear

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController's `viewDidLoad` method try calling

```
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

Comment: Even with this call preferredStatusBarStyle is never call

Answer (score 0):

```
didFinishLaunching Method in AppDelegate Class Single line code.

application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Apple Guidelines/Instruction](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/status-bars/) about status bar change. Only Dark & light (while & black) are allowed in status bar.

*Here is - How to change status bar style:*

If you want to set status bar style, application level then set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO` in your `.plist' file.

if you wan to set status bar style, at view controller level then follow these steps:

1. Set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` in the `.plist` file, if you need to set status bar style at UIViewController level only.
2. In the viewDidLoad add function - `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`
3. override preferredStatusBarStyle in your view controller.

-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Set value of .plist according to status bar style setup level.
[image]